# Javascript Promise - one of my promises function returns undefined, however other similar function works and payload is returned

Tags: javascript

I'm working on Promise. I have constated than one of my promise - the `() => console.log("first callback")`  returns undefined on Nodejs  console and browser's console. I wonder why since there is a value to return and their payload.

Here my snippet :

```js
var promise1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  setTimeout(resolve, 100, 'foo', 
             () => console.log("first callback"), // returns undefined
             console.log("second callback"),
             console.log("...n callback"));
});

promise1.then((data) => console.log("promise data: ", data));
```

if someone have any hint on why it returns undefined, would be great,

Thanks

Comment: `console.log()` *always* returns `undefined`.

Comment: Also it's really unclear what you're asking; that arrow function you pass to through is never called by your `.then()` callback, so it's not apparent how you can even tell that it returns `undefined`. The `resolve()` callback you get from the Promise mechanism will only pay attention to its first parameter anyway.\

Comment: thanks for the hints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call back (resolve in this case) takes only one param. I would refer to [this](http://arguments.callee.info/2008/11/10/passing-arguments-to-settimeout-and-setinterval/)

```js
var promise1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  setTimeout(resolve,100,
             () => console.log("first callback"), // returns undefined
             console.log("second callback"),
             console.log("...n callback"));
});

promise1.then((data) => console.log("promise data: ", data));
```